# Integrating blog in my website

Tags: web, integration, blogs

Is there any blog provider that allows you to integrate the blog under your own website/domain?

I have a site www.aaaaaaa.es and would like to have the blog under www.aaaaaaa.es/blog using my own header, but fully manage the blog with the third party provider.

Comment: You can use wordpress (https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) without problems, you can install it on your domain and call it www.aaaaaaa.es/blog if you want and then modify the header and footer to be exactly as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wordpress. It enables you to make and customize your own blog within your website. [Here is a link to the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to perform an URL Rewrite.
If you have two system under the same server you can use the rewrite module of your web server (in IIS URL Rewrite, in Apache rewrite directive).

Another way is like aruba and other domains does: use an iframe full width so initially you don't see the change of domain, but when you click on one link (such as article) you will not see the change in the URL.

[Futher information to this link](http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/url-masking.php)